# Map arnagoDb Attributes to C# properties

Tags: c#, .net, arangodb

I Use ArangoDB Graph Database with [ArangoDB-NET](https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET)(C# Driver).

how can I map properties of c# object  to attributes of ArangoDB?

more than any thing, I need to mapping when I  insert a document, because of the **ArangoDB's id** create according of this pattern : "CollectionName/_key"

**ArangoDB's id= _key(attribute)**     <================>     **C#' id= Id(property)**

any one can help me?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `AliasField` attribute which should map specified field to property. [Dummy entity](https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET/blob/master/src/Arango/Arango.Tests/Entities/Dummy.cs) in unit tests uses this attribute to map lower case version of properties.

Comment: many thanks for your driver and this response. it's great feature but I don't allow to assign any attribute(annotation) to my properties(in my Model layer). now, did you suggest any thing? for example, applying AliasField attribute  in another way or another layer?

Comment: this trick[AliasField ] works when I insert a document,  but when I get a document, Just fetch non primary attribute(_key), and didn't retrieve _key. and Id property was null... why?

Comment: @KorekiXeri: You somehow need to flag the property that it will contain ArangoDB specific fields (like _id or _key). Unless you don't want to have it named and accessed exactly as e.g. foo._id of foo._key then the only way come to my mind is through attributes. Regarding the fetching - it's hard to figure out what you are trying to do - can you please create an issue on github with some examples. It will be easier to provide solution there.